# Uma query com custo pior pode ser uma query com melhor desempenho?

Tags: sql-server, query, desempenho

### Contexto

Aqui na empresa temos uma query muito complexa que engloba várias regras de negócio, para apresentação em um WorkFlow e por enquanto estou avaliando ela no **SQLServer**.

A performance desta query estava ruim e com o crescimento das tabelas, os DBA nos alertaram a reavaliar a query pois ela está ficando muito custosa para o banco.

Quando comecei a query tinha um custo **[Estimated SubTreeCost = 19.891]**, a partir daí comecei a avaliar e remover alguns campos opcionais, left joins desnecessários, subselects da projeção e o custo aumentou ao invés de diminuir **[Estimated SubTreeCost = 20.232]**

Ao executar a query reduzida, tive o resultado em **23s**  e da query original (com custo menor) **1min18s**

### Pergunta

Não sou muito experiente com avaliação de planos de execução de queries e daí veio uma dúvida, o custo é baseado na quantidade de dados retornados? no tempo de execução? no custo para o banco?

Pode a query com custo maior ser melhor que a original com custo menor?

> *Obs: Não posso compartilhar a query por se tratar de dados sigilosos e a query é bem complexa e seria díficil tentar criar uma query fake semelhante*

Comment: "Há algumas suposições falsas comuns sobre o custo estimado de execução. Em especial, as pessoas costumam pressupor que o custo estimado de execução é um bom indicador de quanto tempo a consulta leva para ser executada e que essa estimativa permite diferenciar planos bons de planos ruins. Mas isso não é verdade.": http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/2007.11.sqlquery.aspx O artigo é bem elucidativo. A parte recortada é só um chamariz :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Estimated SubTreeCost é individual e existe para cada operador criado no plano de execução, então o aumento na estimativa deste operador em específico, não significa uma query mais pesada, mas somente um aumento no consumo da substree deste índice em específico. Pode ser, por exemplo, que a remoção das partes opcionais aumente a quantidade de dados obtidas por essa subtree, mas de um modo geral, diminua o custo total da query para o banco.

Se possível, sempre rode a query, marcando para incluir o plano de dados atual (query -> Include Actual Execution Plan). A estimativa, muitas vezes não condiz com o que o SQL realmente utilizará.

Answer (score 2):

O custo é apenas uma estimativa... Pessoalmente não ligo muito a esse custo mas sim ao tempo de execução. Para mim o mais importante é devolver a informação o mais rápido possível. Todavia, há um custo ao qual dou atenção quando pretendo diminuir o tempo de execução, que é o "Estimated Operator Cost" dos joins e dos indexes. Diminuindo o custo destes operadores tem um impacto quase sempre directo na diminuição do tempo de execução.
Espero ter ajudado.